# Is receiving a daily return on a cryptocurrency investment halal, haram, or makruh?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, investment

I invested in a cryptocurrency.  The company offered a mining and stake pool program.  In that program, they have a return on investment (ROI), so I took a part of it.

For example: buy a 100 coin and invest it into mining and stake pool program.  The contract of program is one year.  Their ROI for 100 coin is 0.4 coins, so I invest in 100 coins.  I take a daily payment, so every day I get 0.4 coins until my contract is done.

So the question is: is it halal or haram or makrooh??